# gatsby-plugin-image | <StaticImage /> Does not display the image

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I want to optimize all the images on my Gatsby site and to achieve that I have installed the `gatsby-image-plugin`.

For the dynamic images, I am using the  **GatsbyImage Component** and everything is working fine, no issues here.

The problem is when I want to render static images using the **StaticImage Component**.

**Here is an example:**

```
import laptop from '@images/laptop.png';
```

If I import the image and I use it this way:

```
<img src={laptop} alt='laptop' />
```

The image shows up correctly on the browser, but if I try to do this:

```
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';
<StaticImage src={laptop} alt='laptop' />;
```

The image is not showing up on the browser and I get the following message in the console:

> Image not loaded /static/laptop-5f8db7cd28b221fc1a42d3ecd6baa636.png

And this error in the terminal:

> Could not find values for the following props at build time: src
> Image not loaded /static/laptop-5f8db7cd28b221fc1a42d3ecd6baa636.png

I have tried to pass as `src` a link of a random image from the internet and the image was displayed on the browser! *Why is it not working when I use the image that I have in my assets folder?*

PS; Reading the plugin documentation I saw that there are some restrictions like **you cannot pass images that are coming from the props**, but this is not the case! I am importing the image directly from the assets folder.

Any leads, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PS; Reading the plugin documentation I saw that there are some restrictions like you cannot pass images that are coming from the props, but this is not the case! I am importing the image directly from the assets folder.

You're importing the image from your assets folder, but you're still passing it to StaticImage as a prop. The correct usage is as follows:

```
<StaticImage src='@images/laptop.png' alt='laptop' />
```

Per the [Gatsby Image Plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#staticimage) documentation, `src` must be type `string`. You're currently passing an object `{laptop}`. Change it to a string with the images file path and it will display.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. The src that I am currently passing is not an object, it is a string. Indeed, If I console.log it, the output is: "/static/laptop-5f8db7cd28b221fc1a42d3ecd6baa636.png" . Anyway, I have tried to pass it like you said and it didn't work :(

Comment: Have you tried directly referencing the filepath w/o the folder alias?
`<StaticImage src='../../images/laptop.png' alt='laptop' />`

Comment: '@images/...' isn't working for me, directly referencing the image src='../images/...' doesn't work either. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The `<StaticImage/>` component `src` prop **can only be a path relative to the source file or an absolute URL.**

Using the import statement to dynamically import an image at runtime is not allowed when working with the StaticImage component, as it expects the image sources to be known and analyzed at build time.

```
// ⚠️ Doesn't work
import logo from "../images/laptop.png";
//or
import laptop from "@images/laptop.png";  
export const Laptop = () =><StaticImage src={laptop} alt='laptop' />;
```

Allowed:

1. Static values or variables within the component's local scope.
2. Variables and expressions within the file's scope.

```
// will work
export const Laptop = () => <StaticImage src="../images/laptop.png" />;

//variables within the component's local scope
export const Laptop = () => {
   const laptopSrc = "../images/laptop.png";
   return <StaticImage src={laptopSrc} />;
};

//A variable in the same file
const laptopSrc = "../images/laptop.png";

export const Laptop = () => (
  <StaticImage src={laptopSrc} />
);
```

for more details about it please read from this official Gatsby doc [link](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-plugin-image/#staticimage)